# How to create a sliding menu on click of a button

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I want to create a sliding menu on click of a Button. I have used Sliding Menu library and Sherlock library. The sliding menu works well on swipe, but my requirement is i want the sliding menu to slide over when i click on the button. Please help.
Thanks in advance

MainPage code

```
package com.ketan.slidingexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Menufragment.MenuClickInterFace{
    SlidingMenu menu;
    TextView text;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.toggle();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListitemClick(String item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.setText(item);
    }
}
```

Menu Page code

```
package com.ketan.slidingexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Menufragment extends SherlockFragment {
    ListView list;
    MenuClickInterFace mClick;

    interface MenuClickInterFace {
        void onListitemClick(String item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mClick = (MenuClickInterFace) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                String i=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                mClick.onListitemClick(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menulist, container, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a click listener on the button and in the click listener just put 
toggle();

Answer (score 0):

Edit the xml of button1 and add the attribute `android:onClick="buttonClick"`.  Then in your Activity, not Fragment, add

`public void buttonClick(View v){ menu.showMenu(true); }`

That should do the trick.

Thanks